# Same hardware/software, significant difference in performance

Tags: performance, hardware

**Introduction**

I have two sets of machines, **set A** and **set B**, with apparently the same hardware/software configuration, but with a significant difference in performance. Machines in **set B** are up to **x4 faster** than machines in set A. However, **if I reboot a machine in set A**, inexplicably it starts performing as expected, like machines in set B. I can't find an explanation for this behavior.

**Hardware configuration**

- Intel `S2600KP` platform
- Dual processor `E5-2630v3`, 8 physical cores, 2.4GHz base frequency, 3.2GHz Turbo frequency.
- `8x8GB RAM DDR4`, 2133Mhz, one module per channel
- None of the machine has SEL events logged by the BMC that could point to a hardware issues.
- None of the machine is triggering any Machine Check Exception during the whole duration of the benchmarks.

All the hardware components are identical in Model/Part Number.

**Settings and software**

- BIOS version and [BIOS settings](https://gist.github.com/marcoguerri/25c3f5a3454bf5a134be) are identical, e.g. `HT` is enabled, `Turbo Boost` is enabled. See the link for details.
- The machines are running the same `64 bits` version of `Red Hat 6` with kernel `2.6.32-504`.

**The Problem**

Machines in both sets are idle, but whatever load I try to run, I get very different results in terms of performance. For the sake of simplicity, I will run all the benchmarks on core 0. The result is reproducible on all cores (both processors).

*Set A*

```
[root@SET_A ~]# uptime
 11:48:40 up 51 days, 19:34,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

[root@SET_A ~]#  taskset -c 0 sh -c 'time echo "scale=5000; a(1)*4" | bc -l > /dev/null'

real    0m43.751s
user    0m43.742s
sys     0m0.005s
```

*Set B*

```
[root@SET_B ~]# uptime
11:50:00 up 15 days, 19:43,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

[root@SET_B ~]# taskset -c 0 sh -c 'time echo "scale=5000; a(1)*4" | bc -l > /dev/null'

real    0m18.648s
user    0m18.646s
sys     0m0.004s
```

**Observations**

**turbostats** 
reports core 0 as being in `C0 Consumption` state and in `P0 Performance` state with Turbo Frequency enabled for the whole duration of the benchmark.

*Set A*

```
[root@SET_A ~]# turbostat  -i 5
pk cor CPU    %c0  GHz  TSC SMI    %c1    %c3    %c6    %c7 CTMP PTMP   %pc2   %pc3   %pc6   %pc7  Pkg_W RAM_W PKG_% RAM_%
             3.15 3.18 2.39   0   3.26   0.00  93.59   0.00   40   46  49.77   0.00   0.00   0.00  46.45 22.41  0.00  0.00
 0   0   0  99.99 3.19 2.39   0   0.01   0.00   0.00   0.00   40   46   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  29.29 12.75  0.00  0.00
```

*Set B*

```
[root@SET_B ~]# turbostat  -i 5
pk cor CPU    %c0  GHz  TSC SMI    %c1    %c3    %c6    %c7 CTMP PTMP   %pc2   %pc3   %pc6   %pc7  Pkg_W RAM_W PKG_% RAM_%
             3.14 3.18 2.39   0   3.27   0.00  93.59   0.00   38   40  49.81   0.00   0.00   0.00  46.12 21.49  0.00  0.00
 0   0   0  99.99 3.19 2.39   0   0.01   0.00   0.00   0.00   38   40   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  32.27 13.51  0.00  0.00
```

**Simplified benchmark**

To simplify the benchmark as much as possible (no FP, as few memory accesses as possible) I wrote the following 32 bit code.

```
.text
.global _start

_start:
      movl    $0x0, %ecx
oloop:
      cmp $0x2, %ecx
      je end
      inc %ecx
      movl    $0xFFFFFFFF,%eax
      movl    $0x0, %ebx
loop: cmp     %eax, %ebx
      je      oloop
      inc     %ebx
      jmp     loop

end:
      mov $1, %eax
      int $0x80
.data
value:
        .long 0
```

It simply increments a register from 0 to `0xFFFFFFFF` twice, nothing else.

*Set A*

```
[root@SET_A ~]# md5sum simple.out 
30fb3a645a8a0088ff303cf34cadea37  simple.out
[root@SET_A ~]# time taskset -c 0 ./simple.out

real    0m10.801s
user    0m10.804s
sys     0m0.001s
```

*Set B*

```
[root@SET_B ~]# md5sum simple.out 
30fb3a645a8a0088ff303cf34cadea37  simple.out
[root@SET_B ~]# time taskset -c 0 ./simple.out

real    0m2.722s
user    0m2.724s
sys     0m0.000s
```

**x4 difference** to increment a register.

**More observations with the simplified benchmark**

During the benchmark, the number of interrupts is the same on both machines, `~1100 intr/s` (reported with mpstat). These are mostly Local Timer Interrupts on `CPU0`, so there's basically no difference in the source of interruption.

*Set A*

```
[root@SET_A ~]# mpstat -P ALL -I SUM 1
01:00:35 PM  CPU    intr/s
01:00:36 PM  all   1117.00
```

*Set B*

```
[root@SET_B ~]# mpstat -P ALL -I SUM 1
01:04:50 PM  CPU    intr/s
01:04:51 PM  all   1112.00
```

For `P-States` and `C-States` holds the same as above.

**perf analysis**

*Set A*

```
 Performance counter stats for 'taskset -c 0 ./simple.out':

        41,383,515 instructions:k            #    0.00  insns per cycle         [71.42%]
    34,360,528,207 instructions:u            #    1.00  insns per cycle         [71.42%]
            63,675 cache-references                                             [71.42%]
             6,365 cache-misses              #    9.996 % of all cache refs     [71.43%]
    34,439,207,904 cycles                    #    0.000 GHz                     [71.44%]
    34,400,748,829 instructions              #    1.00  insns per cycle         [71.44%]
    17,186,890,732 branches                                                     [71.44%]
               143 page-faults                                                 
                 0 migrations                                                  
             1,117 context-switches                                            

      10.905973410 seconds time elapsed
```

*Set B*

```
 Performance counter stats for 'taskset -c 0 ./simple.out':

        11,112,919 instructions:k            #    0.00  insns per cycle         [71.41%]
    34,351,189,050 instructions:u            #    3.99  insns per cycle         [71.44%]
            32,765 cache-references                                             [71.46%]
             3,266 cache-misses              #    9.968 % of all cache refs     [71.47%]
     8,600,461,054 cycles                    #    0.000 GHz                     [71.46%]
    34,378,806,261 instructions              #    4.00  insns per cycle         [71.41%]
    17,192,017,836 branches                                                     [71.37%]
               143 faults                                                      
                 2 migrations                                                  
               281 context-switches                                            

       2.740606064 seconds time elapsed
```

Observations

- Number of kernel space instructions is different due to the control paths which lead to a reschedule. There are no system calls involved apart from a final `sys_exit`. Clearly the number of context switches is higher for Set A.
- There's also a very small difference in user space instructions (`~10M`). This might be caused by the same reason as above? Instructions which lead to a reschedule which are accounted as user space. Or instructions in interrupt context?
- Total number of instructions for Set A is `0.06%` higher, but the number of `L3 cache references` is double. Is this expected? A quick check on cache configuration leads to the same result. Cache are correctly enabled (`CR0: 0x80050033`, CD is 0) and `MTRR` configuration is identical.
- Probably the most interesting value is the instr per cycle. **1 inst per cycle on Set A, 4 inst per cycle on Set B**.

**Final questions**

- Is there an obvious reason that can explain this difference in performance?
- Why machines in Set A are running at 1 instr per cycle while machines in Set B are running at 4 instr per cycle, given the fact that the hardware/software configuration is identical?
- Why rebooting a machine seems to fix this behavior? As explained in the introduction, if I reboot a machine in Set A, it starts performing as expected.

The cause here is either too trivial that I missed it or too complex that can't really be explained. I hope it's the former, any help/hint/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Do you also notice the difference of performance with your main application or in any other way? I ask because the uptime of 51 days caught my attention. 32bit times 10ms is around 49 days. Possibly some error with time base. (On windows, ::GetTickCount() rolls over after about 49 days. Just so you get the idea what I suspect..)

Comment: Oh wow, interesting. I think following up on IPC difference is a way to go. Take pmu-tools (https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools), and run "toplev ./sample.0" on the machine with IPC=1? IPC=4..5 it what I would expect from properly functioning machine on your benchmark.

Comment: Or asking the same in another way: Does any of your slower machines have an uptime less than 49 days?

Comment: @user2225104 Right now I don't have any `Set A` machine with uptime < 50 day. But this behavior was detected since the very beginning, during the first benchmark run (uptime of 5 days). Anyway, even though I wrote 32 bit code for the simplified benchmark, the machines are running a 64 bits OS.

@AlekseyShipilev Thanks for the pointer, I need to find some time to work on it. I have `python2.6` on these machines and I believe pmu-tools requires at least `python2.7` (e.g `collections.Counter`).

Comment: Right now I only look for differences between the 2 sets. One could be uptime. How that leads to the effect I do not even theorize about right now. It could be application errors, kernel, bios - whatever. First I try to correlate the effect with some discriminating factor.

Comment: What is also interesting is the increase in context switches by again - a factor of 4, give or take. (4 * 281 = 1124 ~ 1117). Is there a way to log data regarding the contexts the scheduler is switching between?

Comment: Of course, this fact could be explained with the test running 4 times longer...

Comment: Was searching for any low level means to programatically impact the usage of instruction pipelines on intel processors in this document: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.html#page=93 and found nothing whatsoever. There are the many reserved, undocumented bits in EFLAGs but that appears to be too far fetched...

Answer (score 1):

Of course it would be great if someone could give an answer which allows to fix your problem right away. But I fear, there is no obvious answer. But there might be some directions of attacking the problem not attempted yet:

1. Under the hypothesis, that some of your machines sometimes show the behavior and others never do, one could conclude subtle hardware issues (sporadic, undetectable by means of system diagnostics). The counter hypothesis would be that this can happen to any of your machines.

   - Step 1: Make sure all parts of machines can be tracked in what is to come.
   - Step 2: Pick some of the allegedly "good" machines and run them with the hard drives of some "bad" machines and see if the effect shows.
   - Step 3: Control step. Run "bad" machines with the hard drives of "good" ones and see if the problem shows.

If the effect also shows on "good" machines, there must be subtle differences in the installation (HD content) or the hard disk is the problem.

If the effect never shows on "good" machines, the "subtle hardware issue" theory is kind of confirmed.

2. Look for those differences which "really and clearly cannot cause that - never!". There is the story about the GM engineer who was sent to investigate why a GM car fails to start whenever a owner of that car bought strawberry ice cream but never when he bought vanilla in a shop... In your case, look at where the good and bad machines are placed. More ventilation of the room, less? Closer to some windows and direct sunlight? Closer/further away from some electrical installations (climate control,...)? Different power supply nets of the building? More stuff connected to some power control paths/USV? ... It might not appear to be reasonable at first glance what I suggest here, but hey - your problem is rather sporadic, right? (50 days uptime and your machines "turn" during that period..).

Put the good machines to the physical locations of the bad ones and see what happens.

3. Some of my more painful working days as a embedded software engineer came from people swapping "identical equipment" on my working desk... and me spending half a day - half a week trying to find out why my stuff is not working as it did before I had left for the night... Sometimes even the tiniest revisions of some component (or software/configuration version flashed into it) can have some observable effects. In some of my cases along that line, not even the manufacturer was aware of those "unimportant" changes - sometimes only in some PCB layout or a change of the capacitor supplier to a second source...

Step 1 should help finding such subtle differences, identifying which of your machines work and which do not. Step 3 is about finding the explanation.

4. Try to assess the "MTBF" and analyse it for a pattern. As you can clearly see when a machine starts to slow down, you could measure the average time it takes the machine to go slow. Then, it can be insightful if different machines have different times to failure, if the times are clustering around a value or if there is no pattern at all (totally random when it happens) ...